# VBA passing date parameters to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, parameter-passing

I am facing an issue with date parameters passed to SQL Server stored procedure from EXCEL VBA code.

The stored procedure taking two date parameters `@FromDate` and `@ToDate`. From Excel I want to execute this procedure with the date values taken from cells.

The issue is that, the dates from cells to procedure are passed in the format `"dd/mm/yyyy"` irrespective of any format changes I do in excel cell. Whereas the SQL procedure is accepting the formats `"yyyy-mm-dd"` or `"yyyy-mon-dd"` or `"yyyy/mm/dd"` or `"dd-mon-yyyy"`.

The procedure is throwing an error :

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string" for the dates passed from excel (in the format "dd/mm/yyyy"

The vba code I used is (reference https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservert...to-sql-server/)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim FromDate As Date
Dim ToDate As Date

FromDate = Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") 'Pass value from cell B1 to SellStartDate variable
ToDate = Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") 'Pass value from cell B2 to SellEndDate variable

MsgBox FromDate
MsgBox ToDate

'Pass the Parameters values to the stored procedure used in the data connection
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("TestConnection").OLEDBConnection
.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.spr_TestProcedure '" & FromDate & "','" & ToDate & "'"
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("TestConnection").Refresh

End With
End Sub.
```

Is there any way to pass the dates in the format that SQL Server procedure accepts? If there is no other option, then I will have to take the option to make my procedure parameters type to varchars and convert them to date.

Appreciating your help on this!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Declare your `FromDate` and `ToDate` variables in VBA as Strings. You want to concatenate strings to your CommandText SQL string. Your `Format()` is superfluous otherwise.

Comment: @marc_s, I have edited my question to tag database which is sql server

Comment: @Ralph, Whatever format I use in excel for date,  the VBA shows (on msgbox's) the format dd/mm/yyyy.  For ex, if I enter 2016-sep-25, msgbox shows it as 25/09/2016.  The commandText builds the code as "EXEC dbo.spr_TestProcedure '@FromDate','@ToDate'" which I can see when you right click ->Table->Edit Query.  The .Refresh is the one executing the code.

Comment: @JNevill, yes it is working when I change the FromDate and ToDate as strings.  Thanks for pointing  the option.  So the table query is built with the date formats which SQL expects.  Although I am now stuck that the query is not executing and hence data is not getting refreshed which I except with the code  "ActiveWorkbook.Connections("TestConnection").Refresh"

Comment: Whenever you have a comment such as `that's working. But now..." you can be almost certain that you have a new question for a new post. Hence, I recommend that you post a new question to resolve your new problem. At the same time you should post the answer / solution to your problem here for others to see how to resolve an issue like yours. After all, please keep in mind that this website is not only meant to help you but furthermore this website is meant as a reference for others to find answers to similar problems.

Comment: cool, It works when I declared FromDate and ToDate as strings.  Except that the code is same as I posted.

Comment: The data refresh through VBA code also works after I unchecked "Enable background refresh".  I referred the link http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/388633-refreshing-data-connections-through-visual-basic-applications-only-working-if-macro-stepped-through-debugger.html

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the date to the sp as char() and convert it to date.